# Jack Kerouac once wrote about his "too big world". Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

This is what Jack Kerouac writes in *On The Road*:

> A pain stabbed my heart, as it did every time I saw a girl I loved who was going the opposite direction in this **too-big world**.

I'm wondering if the construction "too-big world" is grammatically correct English, since I'm planning to use it in one of my songs (I'm a songwriter). Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's *grammatical* to create hyphenated compound adjectives, or if the use of "too-big world" is *natural* English?

Answer (score 1):

The term "too-big" is a hyphenated adjective. It is very common in English to lump a bunch of words together and construct a hyphenated single word out of them, especially as a modifier.

For example:

> The **five-year-old** girl is following her grandmother.
>
> This **rock-hard** cake is absolutely awful.
>
> There are some **beautiful-looking** girls in our school.

Therefore it is grammatical to say "this too-big world". However, if you are asking if this expression sounds natural or common enough, that's another can of worms.

Comment: I don’t really see the other can of worms. _The five-year-old girl is following her too-frail grandmother_ – that sounds neither unnatural nor uncommon.

Comment: @J.R. I added that because we don't usually allow hyphenated adverb+adjective combinations. E.g. you can't say "That is a beautifully-looking girl.*" But rather "That's a beautifully looking girl." "Too" is of course an adverb. There are cases where "too" is safe enough to be included in combinations. "All-too-" as in "That reflects an all-too-common goal." Or in combination with other words. E.g. "That is one too-tall-to-tango hombre." "Too-frail" invokes the Skinny Puppy song "Far Too Frail", which I would argue makes it uniquely more tongue-in-cheek.